# change laravel 5.4 text mail content-type to text/plain

Tags: php, email, laravel-5.4

I am sending a queued text mail with laravel:

part of UploadController.php:

```
public function postDelete(Request $request)
{
    $upload = Upload::where('filename',$request->filename)->where('accepted',0)->delete();

    $this->image->deleteFromUploadFolder($request->filename);

    Cache::forget('waiting_uploads');

    $msg = 'upload has been deleted';
    Mail::to('aaaaa@bbbbbb.de')->queue(new TextMail($msg));

    return redirect('upload');
}
```

Mailable (TextMail.php):

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

class TextMail extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $msg;
    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($msg)
    {
        $this->msg = $msg;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->text('emails.empty')
                    ->subject($this->msg)
                    ->with('msg',$this->msg);
    }
}
```

The view `empty.blade.php` should only print the message:

```
{{ $msg }}
```

But neomutt receives text/html content:

```
[-- text/html wird nicht unterstützt ('v' benutzen, um diesen Teil anzuzeigen) --]
```

and thunderbird also shows text/html instead of plain text:

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
```

What can I do to get the mail so that neomutt does not complain?
When using `Mail::send()` I get `text/plain` but not with `Mail::queue()`.

Answer (score 3):

Ok,just logically. `Laravel` uses `SwiftMailer`. Try like this (cann`t check for the moment):

```
Mail::send('emails.empty', ['msg'=>$msg], function ($message) {
    $message->to(....)
    ->subject(....)
    ->getSwiftMessage()
    ->getHeaders()
    ->setContentType('text/plain');
});
```

Explanation: in callback `$message` has method `getSwiftMessage` ( see [.../Illuminate/Mail/Message.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/96d18d958b04e70f7a76cffb73133e91832d7cd6/src/Illuminate/Mail/Message.php)). Via object `SwiftMessage` we get access to `getHeaders` and `setContentType` by `SwiftMailer's` specified class ( see [../swiftmailer/source-class-Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity](http://apigen.juzna.cz/doc/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/source-class-Swift_Mime_SimpleMimeEntity.html#171-186) ).

Comment: The mail is sent, but still text/html.

Comment: when I use `Mail::send()` I can have `text/plain` but not with `Mail::queue()` (both starting a Mailable)

Comment: @haheute Ok, show plz more code. I am convinced it's possible to "override" `content-type`.