# Sending html content as mail body laravel mail sending application

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, send

My controller is

```
public function basic_email() {
  $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi",'roll'=>"123");
  Mail::send(['text'=>'mail'], $data, function($message) {
     $message->to('xyz@gmail.com', 'Basil Baby')->subject
     ('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
     $message->from('abc@yahoo.com','Virat Gandhi');
  });
  echo "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
```

}

My blade is

```
Hi, {{ $name }}
  your roll number is {{$roll}}
  please click on the link to <a href="#">verify your account</a>
```

Mail is being received. but the mail body is displaying html content as such. How to make verify you account a html link in mail body

Comment: [Try this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44741614/2090853)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your key `text` to  `html` in your send function.
`text` key send data as a plain text

```
Mail::send( ['html' => 'mail']...
```

Also change `{{}}` to `{!! !!}`

Reference:
[Laravel -> Mail](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mail)

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to verify registered users, I would suggest you to use `Laravel's` build-in verification system.
You can follow the link:
[Laravel email verification](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/verification)